# how to remove vertical scrollbar from internet explorer 7 on fullscreen?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

My internet explorer version is 9. But I use Browser Mode: IE7 and Document Mode: IE7 standards. My Asp.Net project must viewed on full screen and without vertical scrollbar. How can I remove vertical scrollbar on fullscreen.

I use *overflow:hidden* css code and it removes scrollbar but break down the screen of project and screen didn't shown properly.

Comment: You need to post more detail. Some code (CSS/HTML), a better description of your problem and a link to a live demonstration will help you get answers.

Comment: No one can help you if you don't post any code and don't explain what that means: "but break down the screen of project and screen didn't shown properly".

Comment: @cejoseph If there's content below the fold (where the browser viewport ends), you'll always have the vertical scrollbar. Post more code for us to help OR verify if you have content that can fit in without the scrollbar.

Also, there's no guarantee that users using the browser with a smaller height will not see a scrollbar. You've to check the optimum resolution you're supporting as well.

Comment: if you need any other information I can give.

Comment: @cejoseph, perhaps when you say "remove vertical scrollbar" you really want to say "prevent vertical scrollbar"? If so, try zooming your browsers viewport so that everything becomes smaller, until the vertical scrollbar is no longer present. Read about Zoom [**here**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Zoom-in-on-a-webpage)

Comment: Also, you can remove vertical scrollbar with `overflow-y: hidden` for the `html`, `body`, or *your selector*. But as you mentioned, your page *may break*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in my css file and vertical scroll-bar has gone. Here the solution:

```
#altPanel, .tampon {
height: 4%;    //Changed
}

body {
background-color:#0ff;

margin-top:0;        //Added
margin-bottom:0;     //Added
}
```